# W'y, ter read, o' course

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Here's yer mornin' paper!" yelled a newsboy.

"Mine, did you say?" she asked.

"Sure! Chronicle, 'Quirer, R'public 'n' 'Spatch! **Wot'll ye 'ave**?"

"What are they for?" inquired the wax lady, simply.

"**W'y, ter read, o' course**. All the news, you know."

Source: http://www.classicreader.com/book/2953/1/

I suppose that the passages in bold indicate non-standard spoken English. While I think that the first one could be transformed into "which one do you want"" the second one I am not able to understand.

Comment: It's not only *non-standard **spoken** English* - it's ***very*** non-standard ***written*** English. The orthography ***W'y***, for example, would be completely unfamiliar to most native Anglophones (I can't recall ever seeing it before, and it gives me no clue whatsoever as to how the newsboy speaks. Your text is written in an oddball register combining unusual "stereotypical" vernacular and dated Victorian usages presented in an almost archaic "fairy story" style. It's not a good text for learning about *current, normal* English, spoken or written.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The orthography *why* probably means that the newsboy pronounced *why* with a "w" rather than a "wh" (in IPA, /w/ and /ʍ/). Since nearly everybody uses a "w" today, this eye dialect spelling is obsolete. (And people would probably use "hwy" to indicate those few dialects that retain the /ʍ/.)

Comment: @Peter: Actually, I just thought of that after posting the comment. I still don't recall seeing that orthography, but having watched quite a few (mostly US-produced) westerns lately, I have been struck by how often they were still saying **hw-** even just a few decades ago. But I assume most young Americans find the Family Guy ["Now say cool whip"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAPjCExArA8) skit funny, so I guess it's now as rare in the US as in the UK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think it's very rare in most regions of the U.S. I wouldn't be too surprised if it was still hanging on in a couple of places.

Comment: @Peter: If it's now "dialectal" in the US, does the usage tend to have negative ("uneducated") connotations in the US today? In the UK it carries implications of "upper-class" and "old-fashioned", but it's not really "dialectal" and it's more a marker for *age/class* than education level.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the US, it sounds more cultured, if anything ... but then so does anything that sounds even close to a British accent.  Still, I'm with Brian that it sounds weird, especially when repeated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers **_"ter read"_** is a near-perfect rendition of _"to read"_ as spoken in the "deep Brooklyn" accent still heard at the far reaches of the Brighton Line (Q train.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure English isn't the only language where an author can imitate how a particular dialect *sounds* with alternate spellings and odd punctuation to indicate missing phonemes.

> **Chronicle, 'Quirer, R'public 'n' 'Spatch** = The Chronicle, The Enquirer, The Republic, and (I'm guessing) The Dispatch. (all names of newspapers)
>
> **Wot'll ye 'ave?** = What will you have?
>
> **W'y, ter read, o' course** = Why, to read, of course

This adds color to the narrative because the reader can "hear" the dialogue as if spoken by the character, whose accent and diction illustrate his personality and social class.

You have to sound the words out and make your best guess what they mean.  Even native speakers can have trouble doing this, if the accent is garbled enough.

This, of course, happens frequently in real life.  Like when an American travels to, say, rural England, and can't understand anything even though everyone is ostensibly speaking "English".

[Sometimes you need a translator (from the movie "Hot Fuzz")](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cun-LZvOTdw)